# $('#' + CommentBoxId).val(); not picking up

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

User enters data in comment box and clicks corresponding submit btn.  Im trying to pass id, CompanyId, WorkId, CommentBoxId to code behind to update the record.  So far this all works fine, but I also want to pass the data entered in the commentbox.

```
JavaScript runtime error: Sys.Net.WebServiceFailedException: The server method 'CommentBox' failed with the following error: System.InvalidOperationException-- Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: 'CommentBoxContents'.
```

The values of id, CompanyId, WorkId and CommentBoxId, are all passed correctly. so how can i pass what is entered in the text box?
thank you

---

EDIT:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
   var commentBoxData
   function SubmitButton(id, CompanyId, WorkId, CommentBoxId) 
   {
       var commentBoxData = $('#'+CommentBoxId).val();
        Functions.CommentBox(id, CompanyId, WorkId, commentBoxData);
   }
</script>
```

//Inside a repeater:

```
<th style="width:200px;">
     <input id="Comments" name='<%# GetIdOfCommentBox((int)Eval("id")) %>' 
             type="text" runat="server" value='<%# Bind("Comment") %>' />
    <input id="SubmitComments" type="button"
           onclick="SubmitButton('<%# Eval("id") %>','<%# Eval("CompanyId") %>',
                        '<%# Eval("WorkId") %>','<%# Eval("CommentId") %>');"  />
</th>
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging the parameters and making sure they're what you expect?

Comment: can u show us, what are you passing in > id, CompanyId, WorkId, CommentBoxId

Comment: You may need to post some more of your code, e,g, html and the code which calls SubmitButton.

Comment: @Westie thanks everyone for reply please see my edit.

Comment: @SudipPal please see edit P.S all the parameters passed in are as expected. its only when i try to obtain the data in the text box i get a problem

Comment: You are using id="Comments" in the textbox but you are sending "CommentId" in the parameter. It should match..correct?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `$(CommentBoxId).val()` which is wrong.

```
     function SubmitButton(id, CompanyId, WorkId, CommentBoxId) 
     {
         $('#'+CommentBoxId).val();

        Functions.CommentBox(id, CompanyId, WorkId,  $('#'+CommentBoxId).val(), Test);  
     }
```

please use `$('#'+CommentBoxId).val()` in the `Functions.CommentBox`

Comment: What? I was using  $('#'+CommentBoxId).val();

Comment: if that is not working it dosnt mean you should go out of the way. This is the proper syntex

Answer (score 0):

You could try re-writing your code like this:

```
function SubmitButton(id, CompanyId, WorkId, CommentBoxId) 
{
   var commentBoxId = $('#'+ CommentBoxId).val();
   Functions.CommentBox(id, CompanyId, WorkId,  commentBoxId, Test);  
}
```

** **UPDATE** **

And inside the repeater, the textbox id should be the same as the `SubmitButton`'s `CommentBoxId` parameter:

```
<th style="width:200px;">
     <input id="CommentId" name='<%# GetIdOfCommentBox((int)Eval("id")) %>' 
             type="text" runat="server" value='<%# Bind("Comment") %>' />
    <input id="SubmitComments" type="button"
           onclick="SubmitButton('<%# Eval("id") %>','<%# Eval("CompanyId") %>',
                        '<%# Eval("WorkId") %>','<%# Eval("CommentId") %>');"  />
</th>
```

Answer (score 0):

This line does nothing effective because you are not storing the result of the `val()` call

```
$('#'+CommentBoxId).val();
```

The call to `Functions.CommentBox` will have a null value for the fourth parameter because you are not prefixing the id with the hash.

Try this:

```
var commentBoxIdVal = $('#'+CommentBoxId).val();
Functions.CommentBox(id, CompanyId, WorkId, commentBoxIdVal, Test);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your input has an id of 'Comments' but you are trying to use 'CommentId' in the call.